Given that A linear-time reduces to B, what is the solvable relation?
What can you infer from the fact the problem A linear-time reduces to problem B?

If there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem B, then there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem A
If there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem A, then there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem B

Which one is right, and why?
In addition, if problem A O(n^2) reduces to problem B, and
3. If there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem B, then there exists an _____ algorithm for problem A .
4. If there exists an O(n^3) algorithm for problem A, then there exists an _____ algorithm for problem B .
Which one is right, and fill in the blank.

Where did you get this question? What have you tried so far? As it stands this question just feels a dump of a homework problem without any effort.

This is not a homework. I just saw this question:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100982/given-that-a-reduces-to-b-in-on2-and-b-is-solvable-in-on3-solve-a and the answer doesn't convince me, so I ask some further questions.

$A$ reduces to $B$ in linear time means that you can formulate an instance of $A$ of size $n$ as an instance of $B$ in $O(n)$ time. So, if you can solve $B$ in $O(n^3)$, for sure you can solve $A$ in $O(n^3 + n)=O(n^3)$ time.
The opposite implication does not hold, because maybe $B$ is a more generic and hard problem than $A$ and so you can reduce $A$ to $B$ and make it harder but you can also directly and quickly solve $A$.
The same applies if $A$ reduces in $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^3)$. If $A$ reduces to $B$ with a complexity higher than the complexity of solving $B$, e.g. $O(n^4)$ you have that you can solve $A$ in $O(n^4+n^3)$. In general, if you can reduce $A$ to $B$ in time $O(f(n))$ and you can solve $B$ in time $O(g(n))$, you can say that you can solve $A$ in time $O(f(n)+g(n))$ and you can't say anything about $B$ with respect to $A$.

Please do not answer a homework question without any provided effort, as it encourages this pattern and will degrade the quality of this site : https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14/170920

@EnEm sorry but it seamed to me a pretty elaborate question and I gave a generic explanation rather than just filling the blank spaces. I have not thought it was something like homework

thank you much much. This is not a homework. I just saw this question:  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100982/given-that-a-reduces-to-b-in-on2-and-b-is-solvable-in-on3-solve-a the and the answer doesn't convince me, so I ask some further questions.
